# IBM Bluemix AlchemyAPI Text Extraction Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-extraction, alchemyapi

I'm using AlchemyAPI's text extraction API via Bluemix to get the text of webpages for an app I built. More specifically, the URLGetText call. Customers are complaining that various webpages are not supported due to their text language and are getting the error `unsupported-text-language`. However, the possible error codes listed are 
`invalid-api-key
cannot-retrieve
page-is-not-html`

Is there any way on my end to fix this and allow for more languages? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question may be more appropriate for IBM's support site at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/. Disclosure: I am an evangelist for IBM Watson.